# Automorphism of a group is a group action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a group and let $\Omega$ be a set.

Then, the $Aut\left ( G \right )$ acts on $\Omega=G$

How can I show that this is true?

Thank in advance.

Comment: **Definition** of a group action is a map into Automorphisms of a set which preserves whatever structure you care about.

Answer (score 2):

You need a map $\text {Aut} (G) \times G\to G$. Define it by $(\phi, g) \mapsto \phi (g)$. To show that this is an action you need to check that $(\phi_1\phi_2,g)$ and $(\phi_1,(\phi_2,g))$ map to the same element and that $(\text {Id}, g) \mapsto g$

Answer (score 2):

Another definition of a group $\Gamma$ acting on a set $\Omega$ is a group homomorphism $\Gamma \to S(\Omega)$, where $S(\Omega)$ is the group of bijections of $\Omega$.

With this definition, and the fact that every automorphism of $G$ is a bijection of $G$, we get that inclusion is an (injective) homomorphism $\Gamma = Aut(G) \to S(G)=S(\Omega)$.